# UICollectionView - reloadData but retain existing header positions

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView which is almost working as required but what I would like help with is a way to reload the contents of the collection view but retain the position of the headers, but.... The collection view isn't straight forward as I've implemented a UICollectionViewFlowLayout that adds sticky header functionality. The collection view layout is as follows:

```
 ------------------
 |    Header 0    |  < Section 0, Header Yes, Content No, Footer No
 ------------------
 |    Header 1    |  < Section 1, Header Yes, Content Yes, Footer No
 ------------------
 |                |
 |    Contents    |
 |                |
 ------------------
```

Header 2 is the sticky header a stops at the top of the View and this contains buttons that the user can select that then update the Contents. Currently the datasource is updated and the collection view reloaded this then refreshes the view so that Header 1 becomes visible.

I thought that reloadSections may help?

```
[self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]];
```

Any ideas or suggestions welcomed.